# Where did Deb live towards the end of the season?

Tags: plot-explanation, dexter

Just finishing the 5th season of Dexter and partway through the season Deb ends up going to live with Quinn because of their relationship and because of Dexter's old apartment becoming too crowded for her with the baby and Dexter being there all the time.

After Quinn's betrayal is revealed, it is was never clear about where Deb continued to live.  It was obvious she did not stay with Dexter as Lumen moved into the apartment after Jordan Chase started to get close.  But it is never shown her being at Quinn's apartment after their fight in the interrogation room about Quinn suspecting Dexter as Kyle Butler.

Any ideas where she could have been staying?  I find it very odd that she would not return to the apartment after being confused Quinn's loyalties.

Comment: At Quin's places till he propose him.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - Yes, but she breaks up with him when she finds out he was hounding Dexter. Where did she stay during that time while Lumen was in the apartment?

Answer (score 3):

At some point during season five or six, Debra moves into the apartment which once belonged to a murder victim. She discovered the apartment when she attended the crime scene.

Comment: This was during season 6 *after* the break-up with Quinn, after he tried proposing to her.  It is shown after this final break-up that she lives with Dexter in his apartment, which is after all the business with Lumen